Pre authentication with GitHub pages
I am attempting to use BackstopJS for visual regression testing for Storybook. The stories are published to private GitHub pages. When using Puppeteer as the engine I am just hitting the GitHub login page. Ideally I would like to authenticate before tests. I need to be able to run these tests manually as well as within GitHub actions.
I am not really sure where to start and I struggling to understand the auth pages. Does anyone have any advice?

Happy to change the engine to Playwright if that would be a better option
